# Is "standing" an acceptable verb to use for a building?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

For example is it correct to say, "The restaurant was standing on the side of the highway?"
I also thought of erected. Though I'm not very sure about it.

Is standing acceptable in this case? Are there more appropriate verbs?

Comment: I would only use "erected" if I was talking about the building's construction rather than its location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A building can certainly be standing - [here](http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=123496550)'s an example of that use in journalism.

If you use "was standing" there's an implication that it isn't there any more.  So "stood" might be better.

I would prefer "at the side of the highway" or "beside the highway" rather than "on".

"was erected" has the opposite problem to "was standing" - it sounds like you're discussing the building process.

I suggest "The restaurant stood at the side of the highway".

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one question, why do you prefer *at* over *on*?

Comment: @janoChen, to me, standing "on the side" means that its front wall is right next to the traffic, while "at the side" leaves a little uncertainty for physical separation.  It's a matter of taste though, and the distinction may be a little clearer for a person than a building.  Wait long enough and you'll probably get a dissenting opinion anyway.

Comment: FWIW, I think "by the side" is a better choice. "On the side" requires one to imagine a specific piece of real estate called "the side of the highway", cf. "the car was stuck on the shoulder of the highway". "At the side" is technically correct, but it just doesn't seem particularly typical or idiomatic to me. "By the side" is what I would expect, however the difference between "at" and "by" could very well be dialectic and both would successfully convey the correct meaning.

Comment: @FraserOrr I like your *by* as well.  To me (English English) it conveys a nicer sense of next to than my *at* -- certainly no worse. I would prefer *at* for "the car was parked at the side of the road", but there's a stronger relationship between car and road than between restaurant and road.

Comment: @ChrisH - I'd argue that "was standing" might imply more agency, which could be useful for literary emphasis.  For example, if I write "A tower was standing by the gate" then the guard-like nature of the tower is subtly implied.